# PowerMockito mock indirect static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Class to test

```
public class Randomer {
    public int get() {
        return (int) Math.random() + 1;
    }
}
```

The test class

```
package org.samiron;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher;
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * @author samiron
 *
 */
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Randomer.class, Math.class })
public class RandomerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldAddUpDieRollsCorrectly() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Math.class);
        MemberModifier.stub(MemberMatcher.method(Math.class, "random")).toReturn(2.0);
        Randomer d = new Randomer();
        assertEquals(3, d.get());
    }
}
```

Always getting `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<1>`

Whats going wrong here? To be honest, every time I came across a situation to mock a static function I try to find a way around instead of wasting time. So need your help to figure out the exact solution.

*The sole purpose of the example classes is to demonstrate that Math.random() function is not mocked and therefore not returning the desired value.*

**General realization**

Mocking is a every essential tool while writing tests. Although mocking on instances works quite as expected but mocking static methods seems to be a real complicated with so many combinations of mocking libraries and so many options to support just few simple scenarios. This should be streamlined.

**Libraries used:**

- mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
- powermock-mockito-release-full-1.5.1-full.jar

Comment: So, do you have the option to refactor so that the `Math.random()` call is encapsulated in a class/method that can be properly mocked?

Comment: Also, [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random) should return a value between `[0.0...1.0)`. So why are you mocking the method to return `2.0`?

Comment: Your code works for me. What are your dependencies?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens I updated OP with the jars that I am using, may be something is wrong in the combination I am using. Unfortunately there is no maven here (pls dont get shocked!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a library mismatch here.

In the comments you stated to use the following dependencies (without the convenience of Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I got your code working using these:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So my code does not work with the first dependency right?

Comment: @Samiron I would replace both dependencies with the ones I'm suggesting.

Comment: No doubt, I am doing that. Thanks for your response. But I just wanted to make sure that something is wrong with my combination right? It would also be nice to know exactly why this combination is not working.

Comment: @Samiron Well I would say `powermock-mockito-release-full` contains a bug, because older versions of powermock are also not working for me. Moreover, that dependency is no longer updated, the latest version is from 2015. It's probably renamed.

Answer (score 2):

This test passes thereby proving that the static call `Math.random()` **is** successfully mocked:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// tell PowerMock about (a) the class you are going to test and (b) the class you are going to 'mock static'
@PrepareForTest({Randomer.class, Math.class })
public class RandomerTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldAddUpDieRollsCorrectly() throws Exception {
        // prepare PowerMock for mocking statics on Math
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Math.class);
        // establish an expectation for what Match.random() should return
        PowerMockito.when(Math.random()).thenReturn(2.0);

        Randomer d = new Randomer();

        assertEquals(3, d.get());
    }
}
```

The main differences between this and what you posted in your question are is that I am using ...

- `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Math.class)` and `PowerMockito.when(Math.random()).thenReturn(2.0)`

... instead of:

- `PowerMockito.spy(Math.class)` and `MemberModifier.stub(MemberMatcher.method(Math.class, "random")).toReturn(2.0)`

Also, in your OP the example code uses a mixture of JUnit (`org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner`) and TestNG (`org.testng.annotations.Test`) whereas in my example I am just using JUnit.

The above has been verified with

- `junit:4.12`
- `powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0`
- `powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you and Luciano pointed out, it seems like something is wrong with the libraries I am using. I added the jars that I am using, do you have any hint if there is anything wrong in that combination?